# Laravel livewire passing data between two components not in the same page

Tags: laravel, datatable, laravel-livewire

I'm using Laravel and Livewire for the first time, so apologize if the question is silly.

I've read from Livewire documentation https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events
that

*Livewire components can communicate with each other through a global event system. As long as two Livewire components are living on the same page, they can communicate using events and listeners.*

I have two datatables that need to comunicate, but they're not on the same page.

Is there a possible workaround or solution?
Many thanks.

Comment: I guess something like Laravel Echo can make that work but why do they need to communicate in the first place? Sounds a bit too complicated.

Comment: @IGP the reason is because I get the user id from User Datatable and need to show User Activity Datatable depending on that specific user id. User Datatable and User Activity Datatable are the two Livewire components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route model binding is the answer to that. If you load in one component, for example from a row of User table the id, you can redirect to another component binding the id through the route.
User Table blade

```
<td>
  <a href="{{ route('user.activity', ['id' => $user->id]) }}">View Activity</a>
<td>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('activity/user/{id}', UserActivityComponent::class)->name('user.activity');
```

UserActivityComponent it's going to be rendered once you make click or access it through  tag (in my example case). So, like docs said, you can do this

```
class UserActivityComponent extends Component
{
  public $user;

  public $name;
  public $email;
  
  //....
  public function mount($id)
  {
     $this->user = User::find($id);
     $this->name = $this->user->name;
     $this->email = $this->user->email;
  }
  public function render()
  {
     return view('user-activity-component');
  }  
}
```

and deploy in the UserActivityComponent blade all that you want to show in this

Comment: that sound great. But what methods do I need in the User Activity Component? And how do I have to call the Component in the view, with parameters or no?

Comment: Update the answer above